# I am creating pdf from gridview using asp.net c# iTextSharp but Turkish characters are not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating pdf from gridview using asp.net c# iTextSharp but Turkish characters are not visible

```
                    rapor.AllowPaging = false;
                    rapor.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
                    rapor.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
                    rapor.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
                    rapor.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Caviar Dreams, sans-serif;");
                    rapor.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
                    rapor.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
                    rapor.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                    rapor.RenderControl(hw);

                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F);
                HtmlWorker htmlparser = new HtmlWorker(pdfDoc);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                StringReader sr2 = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                 htmlparser.Parse(sr2);

                pdfDoc.Close();

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text + " " + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + " " + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text + ".pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good idea to use html to pdf conversion (after replacing the placeholder values in the html with your data).

My best tried plugin( free ) for this purpose is **DinkToPdf**
https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf